# Run JS Function on Ajax Success & on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function `newCount` that I run on Ajax success and it is working OK, however, I want to also run the same function every time the window is reloaded but for some reason I'm unable to call the function with `newCount();`

my code:

**.ajax**

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    newCount();
});
```

**.js**

```
function newCount() {

    var sum = 0;
    $('.myclass').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    // update count in html
    $('#myid').html(sum);

}; // end count function

newCount(); // ajax not working when this in place
```

when I add `newCount();` after the function, it will run correctly on page load, but the ajax will no longer work and vice versa.

What am I missing? How can I call the same function from the ajax success and every time the page is loaded?

Comment: Whre havevyou written the newCount() function?

Comment: What are the contents of newCount()?

Comment: `newCount()` function code is (for now) lcoated right after the ajax code inside the html page

Comment: There's no reason the function shouldn't work in both places unless it does something odd. Since you haven't seen fit to provide us with what `newCount` does, we can't help. If you'd like help, please include a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have added the code, for some reason I thought it is not important what code is in there as I believe it is something regarding binding the function

Comment: I think the issue is that you're trying to run the function immediately, instead of when the page loads (and those elements are present on the page). If you used `$(function () { newCount(); });` instead of what you have under your definition, I'm guessing it would work. Ajax likely breaks because there are errors in your console (F12 in most browsers). Good idea to check that while coding.

Comment: Mike, I have tried that too, even creating a new function and calling the new function from the ajax but no luck. I can put the same function inside the ajax, but that is not DRY and kind of dirty way having the same function in there twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I've created this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MBU0WJblPlrZMAPfsR19) to show you how you should call the functions. 
Here is the Javascript code.

```
<script>
    (function(){
      function newCount(msg) {
        alert("message from: " + msg);
      }; // end count function
      debugger;
      newCount("Page load");
      $.get( "data.json", function( data ) {
        alert( "Load was performed." );
      });

      $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        newCount("ajax complete");
      });
    })();
```

EDIT 1
I've changed the Plunker so you can see that also works inside the `$.ajax` success property.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "data.json",
    data: "",
    success: function() {
      newCount("ajax complete");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not sure if I can use this as the `ajaxComplete` function is located inside the `$.ajax({ ... success:` code.

Comment: Dude it's working inside the `$.ajax( ...` as well... I just modified the Plunker.

Comment: You are correct. Your code is working. The issue was elsewhere as I did not update the values before running the script again from the ajax. I will accept your answer as correct since your code is clean and fully functional! Thanks for the help!